# plotting some figures and in x-axis Ipython

Tags: ipython

I am plotting some figures and in x-axis, and `Ipython` gives me format like `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 +2004e3` which means `0=2004` and `1=2005`.

But i want vice versa. Like `2004 2005 2006 2007`... How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Add some of your data and the code snippets so others are better able to debug.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set x-axis labels on a figure plotted using matplotlib's pyplot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919360/how-to-set-x-axis-labels-on-a-figure-plotted-using-matplotlibs-pyplot)